# Drawing under-link diagram using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

i am preparing my latex version of my paper and i need to know how can i handle the reduction diagram like in this figure [image]

Comment: welcome! Would you mind posting a MWE of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

As recreation after excellent lunch :-)

```
\documentclass[boeder=5mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,shapes.multipart}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 3mm,
  start chain = A going right,
    MN/.style = {%My Node
            shape=rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, 
            rectangle split parts=#1,
            inner xsep=0pt, minimum height=4ex, 
            on chain=A
                 },
                    ]
\node[MN=1,label=above:I] {$\pi_1$};
\node[MN=5,label=above:saw] 
            {\nodepart{one}     (
             \nodepart{two}     $\pi_1^r$
             \nodepart{three}   $s_2$
             \nodepart{four}    $o^{\ell}$
             \nodepart{five}    )
             };
\node[MN=1,label=above:him] {$0$};
\coordinate[below=of A-1]   (a);
    \draw[thick]    (A-1) -- (a) -| (A-2.two south)
                    (A-2.four south) -- (A-2.four south |- a) -| (A-3);
    \draw   (A-2.three south) -- ++ (0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might have shortened the vertical parts of the links. Look like steeples ;o)

Comment: You have right. When I draw above picture, I wasn't to serious :-)  since question is request "do-it-for-me"  ... Anyway, I will reduce this distance to about half.

Comment: Add some colour so we get different results… B.t.w., the last element is an *o*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a `tabular` environment and `pstricks`. It can be compiled with `xelatex`, or with `pdflatex` if it is launched with the `--enable-write 18` switch (for MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
I & saw & him \\
 \Rnode{P}{$ \pi _1 $} & \Rnode{PO}{$ (\pi _1 ^r s_2 o^\ell) $} & \Rnode{O}{$ o $}
\end{tabular}
\psset{angle=-90, arm=0.6em,  nodesep=3pt, }
\ncbar[offsetB =8pt]{P}{PO}\ncbar[offsetB =-8pt]{O}{PO}
\pnode[0,-1](PO){O1}\ncline{PO}{O1}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]